# Make it easier to get to the bottom of a user's stats pane

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, user-interface, profile-page

Votes, Tags and Badges live at the bottom of the stats tab on a user's profile, but there's no quick way to get there (that I know of...). It's fine when a user is new, but for people with a lot of questions and answers it takes a lot of scrolling to get there.

I would be loathe to add more tabs to that interface (there are already 7 on there), so can we have something like jump-links at the top of the pane instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pressing <kbd>space</kbd> also moves the page down.

and <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> moves the page up.

(assuming you don't have the focus on an input box)

Comment: also, did you ever consider that there is a **reason** that stuff is at the end of the profile? No, I'm not kidding, the page is ordered the way it is for a reason.

Comment: Yet the badges are displayed on every user's flair, all over stack overflow, but in order to drill down to what the information actually means you have to click on a *nearby* hyperlink and scroll...

Answer (score 2):

How about <kbd>End</kbd>

Also - checking the html, there are named anchors; try using `#badges` and `#tags` - [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29620/banjollity#badges)

Answer (score 2):

Any reason not to press Ctrl-End, or the equivalent keyboard shortcut on your browser? There's no need to duplicate browser functionality IMO. Admittedly this doesn't work so well on some mobile browsers, but most have an easy way of scrolling to the end of a page.

Comment: Any reason not to press Ctrl-End? Because it's Command-Down on this keyboard, Windows boy!

Comment: I had hoped "or the equivalent keyboard shortcut on your browser" was implicit. Editing :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should let your mouse go (or grow a third left/right hand to do a right CTRL+END). It's a good practice. Some mouses allow you to program the 4th, 5th or more buttons to special  keyboard shortcuts. I considered adding [{ keys to mine. This site is not for productivity! ^_^